# How automatically insert null row in database based on foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I am using access with a GUI developed in C#.  The problem I'm running into is, with the constraints I have on my tables, When I add a new row to the Project table, I need to add a null row to my Timecard table.  I know access does not support triggers, so I am confused on how I'd do that.

Comment: Access does support triggers. . When you are in your table's design view look on the design tab for `Create Data Macros`. Those'll do what you want. As for the logic of inserting a null row....

Comment: You're so much better off ditching MS-Access and using SQL Express especially if the GUI is in C#. Regarding your question, you could do a INSERT, then SELECT the value of the Identity and INSERT the Identity as the Foreign Key value. Having code in your database to do this isn't ideal, a Stored Procedure or ORM approach would be much better design.

Comment: I know It'd be more ideal to user SQL server or something along those lines, but It's for my senior project at school and It's due in two weeks.  Too short of time to switch.  How would I setup the macro to insert the null row?

Comment: It should be a non-issue to adjust your GUI to insert that empty record whenever you insert a project record.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late, but I can't conceive of a Project table which would have a FK to a Timecard table. The other way around, sure! Whatever...